# You don’t have permission to write to the folder that the file “Info.plist” is in

Tags: xcode

[image]

I can't close this Xcode window.

How can I close this window?

I want to change the language to Chinese so I edited the Info.plist file. But I can't save this change and I closed the window. This message appears in Xcode.

Comment: Use brute force to solve the problem, first copy Info.plist, then delete Info.plist, rename the copied back, close the edit window and don't save it

Comment: This seems to be a Sonoma bug. I've seen it with other apps (such as Preview).

Comment: with Mojave 10.14 and XCode 11.3 it's the same. It's appeared after I chose, for a mistake, to press the red FIX popup than appears on some c++ compile error. And I've solved with brute force closing of Xcode

Answer (score -1):

Use brute force to solve the problem,

- first copy Info.plist,
- then delete Info.plist
- rename the copied back

close the edit window and don't save it